# Distal to, Proximal to ,Cranial to: What is the meaning of "to"?

Tags: meaning

> "In all patients, the injection was administered proximal to the knee."
>
> "The ankle is distal to the knee."

What is the meaning of "to" in these sentences ?

--- Comparing or a connection, relation between things ?

Comment: I would not include "cranial" in this title at all.  "Proximal" is close, "distal" is far.  I do not know, however, why the convention is to say "distal to" and not "distal from".

Comment: [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/to) feels the need to include a very unspecific 'definition':  << Used in various phrases to indicate how something is related to something else (often followed by a noun without a determiner) ‘made to order’ / ‘a prelude to disaster’ >>.  As [**A**, **B**: **locations distal**] gets the message across, it can be seen that 'to' is almost totally a function word here, bleached of lexicality (semantic meaning). Trying to find a meaning is nowhere near as useful as trying to find one for its usage in 'She went to Hull' (or even 'He went to bed').

Comment: Please, why are you including *cranial* alongside *distal* and *proximal* - let alone *cranial to*?

Answer (score 2):

"to", in **"proximal to the knee"** (and "distal to") means **"in relation to"**.
[**TFD - definition 8**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/to). in a particular relationship with.

In the illustration below, **A** is "nearer the center of the body when compared to the knee."

> - [**proximal**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/proximal#medicalDictionary) - "situated next to or near the point of attachment or origin or a central point."
> - [**distal**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/distal) - "situated away from the point of attachment or origin or a central point especially of the body."

"proximal" and "distal" are anatomical terms that describe location in relation to an origin or to the center of the body.  When we say there is a proximal obstruction in a coronary artery, it means the obstruction is close to its origin. If, on the other hand, we say the obstruction is distal, it means it's located far away from the origin, at its final portion.

This illustration shows that "proximal" and "distal" can also be used in relation to a specific point.

[image]

As you can see, **A** is proximal to the knee and **B** is distal to it. ("A" is closer to the origin of the limb than the knee)

Likewise, **"cranial"** and **"caudal"**, describe how close or far something is to the skull or to the tail of an animal.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanations. but what can we say to using or meaning of '' to '' in this sentences ? which one is that ? please take a look at this ---https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/to ( which article ) (1,2,3,4,5....)

Comment: @englishworker    "proximal (in relation) to"

Comment: The OP is asking about the function of "to" used in conjunction with these adjectives, not the meaning of the words "proximal" or "distal" themselves

Comment: @Azor-Ahai  As I have mentioned above, "proximal to the knee" means "proximal in relation to the knee"

Comment: @englishworker - It’s def 1.1

Comment: @englishworker I've edited.

Comment: We also have *next, adjacent, superior*, and *inferior* all followed by *to*.