# What does the preposition "to" mean in these sentences?

Tags: meaning, grammar, grammaticality

*The tissue sample is cut with scissors just **distal to the ligature**.*

*The tissue **distal to the suture** is cut with a scalpel blade.*

*There's an adorable waitress at the coffee shop **next to my house.***

**The meaning of **''to''** in these sentences corresponds to which item in the dictionary** ?

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/
https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/
https://www.merriam-webster.com/
https://www.ldoceonline.com/

Thank you...

Comment: You posted a link to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/to) which has "1e —used as a function word to indicate relative position". It's probably better to think of "distal" as being followed by a certain preposition, i.e. "to". I feel that your problem is something else, maybe a wider confusion over English prepositions.

Comment: ''  I feel that your problem is something else, maybe a wider confusion over English prepositions '' Yes. Absolutely I agree

Comment: Prepositions have been said to be the most highly polysemous (ie used in the greatest number of different ways, with resulting difficulty in pinning down some usages) words in English. One paper suggested a 3-point scale for say 'on': (a) purely locative, literal spatial (on the roof) // (b) semi-metaphorical, quasi-locative (on the bus / train ...) // totally metaphorical (on call, on fire). But this is broad-brush. Only recently have most dictionaries even attempted an exhaustive list of definitions for these common words. // Note that dictionaries list 'next to' as a phrase (Lexico) ...

Comment: or even a compound lexeme (here, a compound preposition = 'beside' : cf French [à côté de] and 3-orthographic-word [on top of] = 'on' or old-fashioned 'atop') (M-W), and I think this makes more sense than trying to work out if the 'to' here is OED sense 234½ or not. Then 'distal to' patterns on the single lexeme 'next to', though the temptation is to see this as more analytical (rather than phrasal) than the common-or-garden 'next to' is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Distal to, Proximal to , Cranial to: What is the meaning of "to"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/409838/distal-to-proximal-to-cranial-to):

Comment: "a wider confusion over English prepositions" ... maybe something to be asked about in ell.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Prepositions are [***function** words*](https://www.thoughtco.com/content-and-function-words-1211726#:%7E:text=Knowing%20the%20difference%20between%20content,while%20content%20words%20are%20highlighted.) (required for grammar / syntax), not ***content** words* (with information / meaning), so I'm on a bit of a fool's errand attempting to answer this question.

But in all of OP's specific three examples, preposition ***to*** carries a literal "locative" sense. It identifies the ***relative location*** of something by reference to something else nearby (***tissue*** near a ***ligature***, a ***coffee shop*** near a ***house***). In such contexts, there's always an associated adjective/adverb (call it what you like) such as OP's ***distal*** and ***next*** before the "locative" preposition giving more precise information about the spatial relationship between the two relevant nouns.

Comment: You explained the subject perfectly. No one had ever explained to me this way. Well, which article of the dictionaries I have sent is suitable for the examples I have given ? Is there a site or book that you can recommend that specifically includes the examples I have given ( distal to, next to ... )  and explains the '' to ''? I would be very happy if you can help.

Comment: Most native speakers won't even know the "basic" meanings of ***distal*** and ***proximal***, which I'm sure is why people here hastily voted to close your question (because they think you need to have the meanings of *those* words explained - they haven't really noticed that you're asking about common-as-muck ***to***, not the domain-specific medical / biological senses of ***distal*** and ***proximal***). To be honest, even though I knew those basic meanings, I didn't realise that in the medical context they're *specifically* used ***relative to the "fixed" end of a joint in a limb***.

Comment: (Note that **distal** means "at some distance away", and **proximal** means "in proximity, nearby". But don't bother with them unless you're a medical student, because hardly anyone will know what you're talking about! :)

Comment: I will ask on ELU Meta for people to reconsider the hasty closevotes here, because it seems to me that you've asked about the "meaning" of ***to*** in such contexts, but people have closevoted because they mistakenly thought you were asking about the meanings of ***distal*** and ***proximal***. Regardless of whether I can persuade enough people to vote to re-open, you might consider "upvoting" and/or "accepting" my answer here if you feel it tells you what you wanted to know. Of course, if I *can* get it re-opened, someone else might post another answer that you think is better than mine!

Comment: Belay that! Either I'm getting confused, or a moderator has just unilaterally cancelled the erroneous "closevote as duplicate" process before I got around to actually *posting* my request for reconsideration on the Meta site! Things look fine now.

Comment: Thank you very much again. What I understand from all you said is that we need to translate it according to the course of the sentence. By the way I searched several dictionaries. I found a dictionary called Random House Webster's College Dictionary. I would like to know your thoughts about this dictionary.

Comment: My thoughts are that *no* dictionary is really a suitable place to find the "meaning" of "function words" like the preposition ***to***. I see one of the answers here cites definition **23** as being appropriate - but it's not obvious to me how anyone who doesn't already *know* the relevant definition might hope to pick the right one out of dozens of possibilities, And personally I think it's essentially "the same" preposition in *He cut the tissue distal **to** the ligature* and *He is father **to** three boys*, but no dictionary is likely to present things like that.

Answer (score 1):

Oxford Dictionary via Google
distal
situated away from the center of the body or from the point of attachment.
"the distal end of the tibia"

The tissue distal **to** the suture = the tissue situated away from the suture.

The X parallel **to** the floor
The Y perpendicular **to** the wall.

to is used to indicate location.

Answer (score 1):

In the vast entry in the Oxford English Dictionary on the many and various uses of the preposition ***to*** it falls under sense 23.

> 23. Expressing relative position: esp. in Geometry.

The first example is from 1570.

> 1570   H. Billingsley tr. Euclid Elements Geom. i. f. 2v   The right
> lyne which standeth erected, is called a perpendiculer line to that
> vpon which it standeth.

The most recent is from 1892

> 1892   Speaker 3 Sept. 289/2   The high road..runs at right-angles
> to..the lane.

While these examples strictly relate to geometrical theory, the word ***to*** is used in exactly the same sense in the positional expressions ***next to, distal to***. Other positional expressions take different prepositions or prepositional phrases eg ***north of the Azores, at a distance from, to the right of, on top of*** etc. Some require no preposition eg ***inside the tube***, ***outside the box***, but sometimes they take ***of*** - ***outside of the box***.

Comment: You explained the subject perfectly too. Thank you very much...